# All my routes are failing in my Web Api app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've created a simple Web Api app that was working earlier this evening. However after installing Ninject and having some trouble with reinstalling references (accidentally removed some when uninstalling Ninject with Nuget).

I figure it could possibly be due to my Startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel).UseNinjectWebApi(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }

    private StandardKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Here is one of my controllers:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Books")]
```

public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    private IBookService _bookService;

```
private BooksController(IBookService bookService)
{
    _bookService = bookService;
}

[Route("GetAllBooks")]
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
{
    return _bookService.GetAllBooks();
}

[Route("GetBook")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBook(string isbn)
{
    var book = _bookService.GetBook(isbn);

    if (book == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(book);
}
```

However every call I make to any of these routes returns 404, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/api/Books/GetAllBooks
```

As you can see, I'm using Ninject with Owin so I'm not sure if this is contributing to the problem.

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using attribute routing. In order for it to work, you need to call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```